# Applet in index.html not loading with IIS. Works fine when index.html is opened Directly

Tags: java, iis, applet

Applet in index.html doesn't load when hosted in IIS but it works fine when index.html is opened directly.

Total file is deployed in IIS but it is not loading. Here i am using QZ-Print and here deployed code:

```
  function deployQZ() {
    var attributes = {id: "qz", code:'qz.PrintApplet.class', 
        archive:'qz-print.jar', width:1, height:1};
    var parameters = {jnlp_href: 'qz-print_jnlp.jnlp', 
        cache_option:'plugin', disable_logging:'false', 
        initial_focus:'false'};
    if (deployJava.versionCheck("1.7+") == true) {}
    else if (deployJava.versionCheck("1.6+") == true) {
        delete parameters['jnlp_href'];
    }
    deployJava.runApplet(attributes, parameters, '1.5');
}
```

Comment: What does you mean `it doesn't work`?

Comment: Applet is not loading through IIS

Comment: What's the IIS error code when the browser makes a request to the applet url?  (You can use fiddler to examine the web traffic on your machine to see the web traffic if you can't request the applet directly)

Comment: it is not showing any error code,  html content is loading but applet code is not working

Comment: Be sure the [Java Console](https://www.java.com/en/download/help/javaconsole.xml) is configured to show when debugging applets or JWS apps.

Comment: `deployJava.runApplet(attributes, parameters, '1.5');` Any use of `deployJava` that requests a JRE < 1.7 will apparently be provided with 1.7 as far as I last heard.  Seems Oracle isn't prepared to spend time patching/updating older JRE versions.

Answer (score 0):

> > "What's the IIS error code when the browser makes a request to the applet url? (You can use fiddler to examine the web traffic on your machine to see the web traffic if you can't request the applet directly)"
>
> "it is not showing any error code, html content is loading but applet code is not working"

Java applets have been blocked by most browsers for many years now, so I'm only answering this for completeness sake...

The Java Control Panel has a way to [enable `trace` logging](https://www.java.com/en/download/help/javaconsole.xml) in the Advanced Tab of the Control Panel plugin which should explain why the applet is not loading.

**The most common cause:**

The `.jnlp` file is what WebStart uses to launch the applet.  Unfortunately, the `.jnlp` mimetype isn't a default mimetype with IIS, so it needs to be added manually for a Java Applet to work.

On your site you need to add a new Mime Type using:

- Extension: `.jnlp`
- Mime Type: `application/x-java-jnlp-file`

Similar discussion:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/qz-print/9BHnAWJCo9w